# Reduce size of JSON serialized by fabric.js after image resize

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

An image is loaded to the fabric canvas using file input and FileReader.  We use scaleToWidth and scaleToHeight to have large photos fit to the canvas.

When I use choose a large 3.2MB jpeg the image is nicely resized to 1MB which is what we want.  We then prepare the data for storage on local indexed db;

```
    canvas.toJSON(); // 4.2MB
    canvas.toDataURL(); // 1MB
```

It seems that the toJSON method stores the original jpeg.  Can we reduce the jpeg prior to serialization ?

I'd prefer to serialize to JSON so we can use other excellent Fabric features in the future.

Comment: `toJSON` and `toDataURL` return two different things. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara We capture image from camera and persist it to indexed-db.  We are currently storing the flat base64 image via the dataurl method.  
In the future we want to store the whole canvas.js object so user edits, text and freedrawing are also stored in an editable format.

Comment: Have you tried `toDatalessJSON` — http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toDatalessJSON

Comment: Send the image back to your server and use GD or ImageMagick libraries to resize. (PHP) You could also look at cloud services like Amazon's SWF. I don't know of any Javascript libraries that are going to make this happen on the client side.

Comment: thanks @kangax toDatalessJSON didn't reduce the image from the original size however i think we've found a way to achieve the requirements as answered below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have this figured by ;

1. loading the photo to Fabric.js canvas
2. then exporting it (which reduces the image to the canvas dimensions) and
3. reloading reduced image data back on the canvas and
4. removing the original full size photo.

Now the fabric.js canvas data is nicely reduced for storage in local indexeddb;

```
    // camera image // 3.2 MB
    canvas.toJSON(); // 1 MB 
    canvas.toDataURL(); // 1 MB
```

javascript

```
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            var img = new Image();
            var opts = {};
            img.onload = function () {
                var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, opts);
                if (imgInstance.getWidth() > canvas.getWidth()) {
                    imgInstance.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
                }
                if (imgInstance.getHeight() > canvas.getHeight()) {
                    imgInstance.scaleToHeight(canvas.getHeight());
                }
                canvas.add(imgInstance);
                canvas.renderAll();
                img = null;

                /* now that the image is loaded reduce it's size 
                so the original large image is not stored */
                /* assumes photo is object 0, need to code a function to       
                 find the index otherwise */
                var photoObjectIx = 0; 

                var originalPhotoObject = canvas.getObjects()[photoObjectIx];
                var nimg = new Image();
                nimg.onload = function () {
                    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(nimg, { selectable: false });
                    canvas.remove(originalPhotoObject);
                    canvas.add(imgInstance);
                    canvas.renderAll();
                    nimg = null;
                };
                nimg.src = originalPhotoObject.toDataURL();

            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally compress big json data and then decompress it on the server...

[Deflate in JS](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate) - nice script to `gzdeflate` (compress) `JSON`.

and then... in PHP:

```
<?php
   $json = gzinflate($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

Comment: gzdeflate is nice.  in our case we would prefer to store the canvas data client locally with indexed-db as the user may have poor or no internet connectivity